# Jquery Uncaught TypeError on Custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null** in `console` but my function looks fine I don't know why its causing this error every time how ever other functions like this I prepared works totally fine
Here is working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/3Lxkkk8k/)

Here is the part of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var URLCheck = document.referrer;
    var frameLocation = URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
    var whiteLocation = 'mywebsite.com';
    if (whiteLocation == frameLocation) {
        $('#adprimary').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [**String.prototype.match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null` if no match was found and you're trying to access the attribute `1` of `null`.

Check if it's `null` before accessing any attributes:

```
var frameLocation = URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/);
if(frameLocation !== null) {
  frameLocation = frameLocation[1];
}
```

Or the short version:

```
var frameLocation = (URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/) || [])[1];
```

Inside your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var URLCheck = document.referrer || ''; // make sure referrer is a string
    var frameLocation = URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
    if(frameLocation !== null) {
      frameLocation = frameLocation[1];
    }
    var whiteLocation = 'mywebsite.com';
    if (whiteLocation == frameLocation) {
        $('#adprimary').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer when I put it in a frame its showing `Uncaught ReferenceError: frameLocation is not defined` in console

Comment: The error means that somewhere in your code you're using a variable named `frameLocation` which wasn't defined before. So add your code to your question or open a new one.

Comment: the error is resolved but when using the same function in an iframe which should remove `#adprimary` DIV won't removes it at all I don't know why but it keeps getting `frameLocation` as null value

Comment: Then your RexExp is not matching the frame's document.referrer. Without the actual code we cannot help you.

Comment: Ok I understand your answers are quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. the document.referrer may not exists;
2. the `URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)` may be undefined

Comment: URLCheck.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/) will never be `undefined`. It can only be `null` or an `Array`.